# Show-hide specific table rows based on which button clicked

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, html-table, show-hide

Working on a **table** which **hides rows** using a **toggle/on-click** action. a **CLASS** or an ID, depending on which button has been clicked. Everything is showing on first page/table load, clicked on a button, anything with that CLASS ID will remain, everything else vanishes/becomes hidden until another button is clicked.  Some times will have more than one targettable class, so it is possible to cause them to be viewable with different button clicks. I will have a total of seven buttons, possibly more later, I've placed my latest attempt below which is being run in a bootstrap 4 framework, but I've removed all bootstrap elements for the moment as I try to resolve the hide/show behavior. I have googled on the subject, I have looked through the javascript fiddle, stackoverflow, w3schools, and several other resources, I've found some examples which do something akin to what I am trying to do, but I have not been able to successfully repurpose the examples.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<link src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#taken').on('click',function(){   
        $('.taken').toggle();
   });
});
</script>

<input type = "button" name = "all" id="all" value = "all" >
<input type = "button" name = "taken" id="taken" value = "taken" >
<input type = "button" name = "open" id="open" value = "open" >


<table style="width:100%" id="testing">
    <tr class="all   taken">
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th> 
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="all   open">
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="all   open">
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="all   taken">
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works, so what's the ask?

Comment: When i run it, it doesn't work SO my only conclusion is that I'm doing something wrong somewhere - i get an odd unterminated error that i can't figure out resolve

Comment: I've managed to get it kind of working, so now i have a different question and will ask that question.